# How can I multiply a n*m DataFrame with a 1*m DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I have 2 pandas DataFrame that I want to multiply:

```
frame_score: 
   Score1  Score2
0     100      80
1    -150      20
2    -110      70
3     180      99
4     125      20

frame_weights: 
   Score1  Score2
0     0.6     0.4
```

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

frame_score = pd.DataFrame({'Score1'  : [100, -150, -110, 180, 125], 
                      'Score2'  : [80,  20, 70, 99, 20]})

frame_weights = pd.DataFrame({'Score1': [0.6], 'Score2' : [0.4]})

print('frame_score: \n{0}'.format(frame_score))
print('\nframe_weights: \n{0}'.format(frame_weights))

# Each of the following alternatives yields the same results
frame_score_weighted = frame_score.mul(frame_weights, axis=0)
frame_score_weighted = frame_score * frame_weights
frame_score_weighted = frame_score.multiply(frame_weights, axis=1)

print('\nframe_score_weighted: \n{0}'.format(frame_score_weighted))
```

returns:

```
frame_score_weighted:   
    Score1  Score2
0    60.0    32.0
1     NaN     NaN
2     NaN     NaN
3     NaN     NaN
4     NaN     NaN
```

The rows 1 to 4 are `NaN`. How can I avoid that? For example, row 1 should be `-90   8` (-90=-150*0.6; 8=20*0.4).

For example, Numpy may broadcast to match dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: for arbitrary dimension, try using `values` to manipulate the values of the dataframes in an array-like fashion:

```
# element-wise multiplication
frame_score_weighted = frame_score.values*frame_weights.values

# change to pandas dataframe and rename columns
frame_score_weighted = pd.DataFrame(data=frame_score_weighted, columns=['Score1','Score2'])

#Out: 
   Score1  Score2
0    60.0    32.0
1   -90.0     8.0
2   -66.0    28.0
3   108.0    39.6
4    75.0     8.0
```

Just use some additional indexing to make sure you extract the desired weights as a scalar when you do the multiplication.

```
frame_score['Score1'] = frame_score['Score1']*frame_weights['Score1'][0]
frame_score['Score2'] = frame_score['Score2']*frame_weights['Score2'][0]

frame_score
#Out: 
   Score1  Score2
0    60.0    32.0
1   -90.0     8.0
2   -66.0    28.0
3   108.0    39.6
4    75.0     8.0
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, when `pd.DataFrame` is multiplied by a `pd.Series`, `pandas` aligns the index of the `pd.Series` with the columns of the `pd.DataFrame`.  So, we get the relevant `pd.Series` from `frame_weights` by accessing just the first row.

```
frame_score * frame_weights.loc[0]

   Score1  Score2
0    60.0    32.0
1   -90.0     8.0
2   -66.0    28.0
3   108.0    39.6
4    75.0     8.0
```

You can edit `frame_score` in place with

```
frame_score *= frame_weights.loc[0]
```